# Text + copy to clipboard

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

In my window I have a read only text that I want the user to be able to copy to clipboard.

I've tried `TextInput` with read only mode, but this did not help.
I can't select the text by mouse to be able to copy it then.

Is there a built-in solution?

I use Qt 5.9.2.

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 900
    title: qsTr("MY APP")
    TextInput
    {
        text: "MY TEXT"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 35
        readOnly: true
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enable mouse selection, you can set [TextInput::selectByMouse](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#selectByMouse-prop) to `true`. This makes it possible to copy from a read-only editor:

```
TextInput {
    readOnly: true
    selectByMouse: true
}
```